# How do I point one virtual host to another instance of apache running at another port on the same box?

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, redmine

I've got two apache2 instances running on my box. One came with a bitnami redmine stack which sole purpose is to host Redmine at host:8080/redmine. The other apache instance is running with php and such and is where I specify all the VHosts for my domains.

Now I'd like to point redmine.somedomain.com at www.somedomain.com:8080/redmine so that redmine is accessible through a subdomain and on port 80. Redmine is a Ruby on Rails app and runs with Phusion Passenger so I can't just point the vhost to the htdocs directory of the redmine install.

How is this done? I've tinkered with ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse but I just can't get it working.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for basic applications. I'm not familiar with redmine, so I'm not sure this will work.

```
ProxyRequests Off

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

<VirtualHost redmine.example.com:80>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/redmine
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/redmine
</VirtualHost>
```

There's more information on [Running a Reverse Proxy](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/reverse-proxy-apache.html) if your application doesn't like this configuration. It happens sometimes when web applications get picky about the HTTP headers, or similar aspects of incoming requests.

Comment: I'm able to navigate to the redmine application now and I can see the frontpage text, thanks. However, there's no stylesheet present and if I click on one of the links I get a 404.

Comment: Actually, what seems to be the problem is that the links on the front-page has /redmine appended to the url.. So the url would in fact become; redmine.mydomain.com/redmine/projects .. As redmine.mydomain.com is already pointing at the root of redmine this becomes an issue

Comment: You'll need to change the `ProxyPassReverse` line. It changes the URLs in the proxied pages so the links work. If you see links on the page that point to redmine.mydomain.com/redmine then the line should be `ProxyPassReverse / http://redmine.mydomain.com/redmine` (probably).